# Cordova | iOS - Origin app://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 200

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, cordova, cors

i try loading a JS-File (contacts.js) from a Webserver but my app said

```
Failed to load resource: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 200
```

In my config.xml i have the `<access origin="*" />` already.

Following this question I found earlier, i added the following code to my config.xml

```xml
<preference name="scheme" value="app" />
<preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
```

Now the error is still there, but the error text is a bit different.

```
Failed to load resource: Origin app://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 200
```

Now that the origin is **app://localhost**, the error still remains.

In Addition: The console also logs the error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load {url} due to access control checks.
```

Cordova-Version: 11.1.0

I did some google searches and stackoverflow searches but nothing solved the problem.

Comment: I am having the same issue after upgrading to MacOS 13 and XCode 14.3.1. I also had Cordova 12.0.0 installed on my Mac, but then I downgraded to Cordova 11.0.0 and it dit not work either. However, it was working perfectly when I had MacOS 11.5 and XCode 13. I don't know if it's related to the OS or XCode version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with your back end. You need to enable CORS on your server and allow request from `app://localhost`